# Need concept or pictorial representation "thinking code"

Tags: logo, symbolism

I need to insert a small logo where I can convey that code can think or thinking code.

Is there way to represent that in very small logo form?

Comment: It would help if you flesh out the "design brief" a bit better. What do you want people to think when they see it? As stated below, is it the code that is thinking? Computers do the thinking, though they think in code if you are talking about AI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ones and zeroes generating a thought bubble with a lightbulb?

more to the point, how can code *think*?

Comment: I was thinking ones and zeroes IN a thought bubble. If you do a lightbulb, in these enlightened times, it has to be a CFL. :-D

Comment: I hate those things, man. I'd rather burn the money on an old-fashioned incandescent than have all that mercury in the house. I'm fairly clumsy and I break bulbs a lot. [/offtopic]

Comment: Well, if you have a flat-screen TV or computer monitor, or a laptop, at home, you already have a bunch of fluorescents, since LED backlights are a recent development and not yet universal. Considering the amount of mercury in older thermostats, not to mention thermometers, I don't have a problem with them. There are several makes on the market now with enclosed bulbs that are REALLY hard to break... ;-)

Comment: true, but I don't drop TVs, monitors, and laptops with the frequency with which I break lightbulbs. The risk of exposure is much lower. I look forward to the higher-standard incandescents.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always partial to a silhouette of a human head with a microchip in it, but this likely won't work for a "very small" icon.

What level of thinking is your code doing?  Does the icon represent "do some incredibly complex heuristics", or does it just represent "make the code do the thinking for me".  Depending on the associated action, you could do a pictorial representation of a decision tree - something as simple as a few lines and small boxes arranged in a flowchart may work for this.